# Is it possible to ignore a particular executable file using .gitignore?

Tags: macos, git, gitignore

Suppose I get `myProgam` executable file on Mac as a result of compiling my code like this:

```
 gcc -o myProgram myProgram.c
```

How can induce my `.gitignore` file to actually ignore the `myProgram` file? I'm not looking for the solution where I make a separate folder for my executable files.

My question might seem obvious to many but I cannot actually find any solution online although I've searched a few pages and tutorials already as well as the StackOverflow resources.

I'll be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Try including that exact program name in your `.gitignore` file.  Not 100% certain that will work at this moment so I'm not posting it as an answer.

Comment: `myProgram` in .gitignore

Comment: I usually add a `*.dSYM` line to my `.gitignore` files too (and `a.out` and `core` and `*.o` and ...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
myProgram
```

on a separate line in your `.gitignore` file

Comment: that's true: both `myProgram` and `/myProgram` work.